# How can I see the passed parameter to the method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{

    //some logic
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

I need to see contextKey variable.

So I tried to use this rows inside the method above:

```
Response.Write(contextKey); 
Response.End();
```

When I try to use row above, I get this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Response.get'
```

The problem is that my method is static and I can't use Response class.

Any idea if there is some alternative way to see the `prefixText` value?

The project doesn't have a solution. I open it in notepad++.

Comment: Since `Reponse` is a member of the class you need to remove the `static` keyword from the method in order to be able to access it.

Comment: Why is your method static in the first place?

Comment: If you just want to see it for debugging purposes why not use `System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine` and see the results in output.

Comment: @J.N. I work on existing project it was designed by another developer.

Comment: @Emad, where can I see the output?

Comment: You could simply write it to a log on the server

Comment: In visual studio output window. Or if you don't have VS in standard output of the host executor.

Comment: @Emad I added this row:

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prefixText);

And opened in VS and attached to the preocess but output is empty.

Comment: Then it's not called. See the documentation for `System.Diagnostic.Debug` for more info. This is works only in debug build.

Comment: Did you try removing  static word? How are you debugging  by the way?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya as Zohar sagested I create log

Comment: Are you calling this service  from browser or some service client and the observe the log?